# Beginner PHP $_POST issue (input type?)

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out what's going wrong here. I'm trying to post a question number to the page, so as you answer questions it increments up. For some reason I can't get it to post, the only way I got it to work was when I include var_dump($q_num); after the part where I increment the $q_num variable. 
I'm assuming this is something very simple but I'm not sure what it is. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!
I know I should sanitize the input, and I've tried a FILTER

```
<?php 
    include('inc/quiz.php');
    session_start();
     ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Math Quiz: Addition</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['page'])){
        $q_num = (int)$_POST['page'];
    } else {
    $q_num = 1;
 }
$p_num = 10;

?>
<?php var_dump($q_num);?>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="quiz-box">
            <p class="breadcrumbs">Question #<?= $q_num;?> of <?= $p_num;?></p>
            <p class="quiz">What is <?php 
            ?> </p>
            <form action="index.php" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?php ($q_num+1);?>" />
                <input type="submit" class="btn" name="answer" value="135" />
                <input type="submit" class="btn" name="answer" value="125" />
                <input type="submit" class="btn" name="answer" value="115" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html
```

Comment: You need to `echo` the value in the `input`. `<?php echo ($q_num+1);?>` or shorthand as you've done elsewhere `<?= ($q_num+1);?>`

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?php echo ($q_num+1); ?>">`